# How to setup nodemon with Apostrophe CMS 2?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Trying to make development with Apostrophe smoother.  Running nodemon with app.js and although nodemon detects changes it does not restart the server and i get `[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/0` from Nodemon.
I understand that Apostrophe does some asset auto generation.  What's the best way to setup Nodemon to watch for changes?

Comment: Please describe the steps you took to set up nodemon, and clarify what files you are modifying when nodemon fails to pick it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that nodemon does not watch .html files by default. Here's a nodemon.json file that works for me:

> {
>     "restartable": "rs",
>     "verbose": true,
>     "env": {
>       "NODE_ENV": "development"
>     },
>     "ignore": [
>       ".git",
>       "node_modules/*"
>     ],
>     "watch": [
>       "lib"
>     ],
>     "ext": "js html json"
>   }

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but we added support for `nodemon` in Apostrophe 2. Check it out:

*[Adds nodemonConfig](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-boilerplate/pull/10)* and *[Prevent restarting of nodemon in some edge cases](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-boilerplate/pull/11)*.

As you can see, this is part of the boilerplate. Each `apos create-project` using [apostrophe-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-cli) will add that config to your `package.json`. But you could easily add this to your existing projects, of course.

Let us know about any unexpected behavior.